# How to change the text 'This app may post on your behalf..' to custom text

Tags: facebook

When using 'publish_actions' permission  on facebook, the pop up window shows the text 'This app may post on your behalf, including status updates, photos and more.' by default. can we change the text to some app specific custom text?

Comment: I would hope not, given that allowing the text to be changed would allow app developers to prevent that warning being presented to users.

Comment: No, of course you can not change that.

Comment: Please see the link http://newspaperarchive.com/login , click login with facebook. There the text is 'This app may post on your behalf, including articles you were featured in, articles you read and more.'.